# Whats quicker - Multiple PDO queries or Array Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am just wondering which way to go with a database query. I have started using PDO recently with mysql. I am writing a small script that checks for manufacturers and then it checks items against each manufacturer. I am stuck whether it would be quicker to place the items in an array and (only use 1 query) then as i loop for the manufacturer array use an array_count_values to get the item quantities or do a seperate query in the loop to count the items.
I have about 400 manufacturers and 70000 items at present.

my current code using array is :

```
$itemquery = $conn->query("SELECT manufacturer FROM item_info_short");
$itemquery->execute();
$itemrow = $itemquery->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($itemrow as $itkey => $itvalue) {
   $items[] = $itvalue[manufacturer];
}
$it_qty = array_count_values($items);
```

and then for my loop :

```
$manu_query = $conn->query("SELECT manufacturer FROM manufacturers ORDER BY manufacturer");
while($rowsx = $manu_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $rowid = $rowsx[manufacturer];
    $count = $it_qty[$rowid];
    if($count == '') $count = 0;
    echo "<option value=\"$rowsx[manufacturer]\">$rowsx[manufacturer]&emsp;$count Items</option>";
}
```

As you can see i use 2 PDO queries altogether.
The other method would use 401 queries.

I am trying to see which method is best practise and/or quicker.

Thanks in Advance for any advice.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it and see?

Comment: There is a problem with questions on Stackoverflow. People don't read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your question is irrelevant to PDO
2. You're doing it extremely inefficient way, but it's irrelevant to the question you've asked.
3. The question you have to ask have to be not "which is faster" but "which is proper way".

To get count of manufacturers with cout of their goods, you have to make SQL to count them for you

```
SELECT manufacturer, count(*) cnt FROM item_info_short GROP BY manufacturer
```

will return all manufacturers with their goods count
if you want to get manufacturer details along - join this query with manufacturers table

if you need to list all manufacturers with their goods - use LEFT JOIN
something like this

```
SELECT m.manufacturer, count(i.manufacturer) cnt 
    FROM manufacturers m LEFT JOIN item_info_short i
    ON i.manufacturer = m.manufacturer GROUP BY m.manufacturer
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tend to agree 'which is proper way' should be question title. Just 2 questions, How do I make it show all manufacturers including ones with 0 values and can you also show me the join statement you would use ?

Comment: I am trying to use the left as you recommend but it does not give the results i would expect. i.e. no 0 qtys the 0s seem to end up as 1 plus more results than there are manufacturers..                 SELECT item_info_short.manufacturer, count(*) cnt FROM item_info_short LEFT JOIN manufacturers ON ( item_info_short.manufacturer = manufacturers.manufacturer )GROUP by manufacturer ORDER BY manufacturer ASC

Comment: Thank you again. Im guessing the left join method is better than a using a sub-select as i have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 'Your Common Sense' for your assistance but it still did nt show me 0 results against manufacturers that were not in the 'item_info_short' table.

```
SELECT m.manufacturer, 
      (SELECT COUNT(i.manufacturer) FROM item_info_short i 
                     WHERE m.manufacturer = i.manufacturer) cnt 
      FROM manufacturers m ORDER BY m.manufacturer ASC;
```

This was the final mysql statement I actually have used which gives me a full list of manufacturers and their quantities from item_info_short including 0 values. In answer to my own question this method is alot quicker than putting into an array first, and i believe this to be the correct way.

Comment: Let me suggest you to ask another question, providing table structures and desired result. You don't need sub-select though. Left join it should be.

Comment: Ill try more clearly.. I have a table called manufacturers with id,manufacturer,details,image i then have a products table with a few columns but 1 is called manufacturer. I wanted to list all manufacturers and ids with a qty of items that are listed with that manufacturer. Some manufacturers may not have any items listed. So the list would comprise of id manufacturer and qty.